# angular compodoc tool ignoring *.d.ts files

Tags: angular, typescript, documentation, compodoc

I am using compodoc to generate documentation for my angular project, but it ignores all .d.ts files, even I include all .d.ts file in tsconfig.compodoc.json as below:

```
{
  
  "include": [   
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]  
}
```

running command:

```
compodoc -p .\tsconfig.compodoc.json
```

sample output:

```
[12:20:28] Including      : F:\Projects\WebGPNet\frontend\projects\map-core\src\SnapCapability.ts
[12:20:28] Including      : F:\Projects\WebGPNet\frontend\projects\map-core\src\test.ts
[12:20:28] Including      : F:\Projects\WebGPNet\frontend\projects\map-core\src\VertexHighlighter.ts
[12:20:28] Including      : F:\Projects\WebGPNet\frontend\projects\map-core\src\VLayer.ts
[12:20:28] Ignoring       : F:\Projects\WebGPNet\frontend\projects\map-core\src\interfaces\ActionModel.d.ts
[12:20:28] Ignoring       : F:\Projects\WebGPNet\frontend\projects\map-core\src\interfaces\ActionsGroup.d.ts
[12:20:28] Ignoring       : F:\Projects\WebGPNet\frontend\projects\map-core\src\interfaces\BackgroundColor.d.ts
[12:20:28] Ignoring       : F:\Projects\WebGPNet\frontend\projects\map-core\src\interfaces\ContextMenuItem.d.ts
```

How to include those files?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the compodoc source codes, and there are hard-coded lines which ignores the .d.ts files. I made a fork and fixed it for anyone has this issue:

https://github.com/zatkhahi/compodoc/tree/ignore-d-ts

Comment: can you help me doing the same got spec.ts files too